# What is the limit of holding the data in viewstate?

Tags: viewstate

What is the limit of data we hold in ViewState? And are the limitations of Viewstate?

```
ViewState["allDataOfCandidates"]=dt;
```

Regards,

Ganesh. 
http://www.twitter.com/ganeshatkale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewstate does not have any size limitations. But nothing comes for free, and view state is no exception. It certainly imposes performance hits whenever an Asp.net webpage is requested.

1. On all page visits, during the save view state stage the Page class gathers the collective view state for all of the controls in its control hierarchy and serializes the state to a base-64 encoded string. (This is the string that is emitted in the hidden __VIEWSTATE form filed.) Similarly, on postbacks, the load view state stage needs to deserialize the persisted view state data, and update the pertinent controls in the control hierarchy.
2. The __VIEWSTATE hidden form field adds extra size to the Web page that the client must download. For some view state-heavy pages, this can be tens of kilobytes of data, which can require several extra seconds (or minutes!) for modem users to download. Also, when posting back, the __VIEWSTATE form field must be sent back to the Web server in the HTTP POST headers, thereby increasing the postback request time.

If you are designing a Web site that is commonly accessed by users coming over a modem connection, you should be particularly concerned with the bloat the view state might add to a page. Fortunately, there are a number of techniques that can be employed to reduce view state size. You just have to turn off the view state tracking for that control.

For additional information you can go through - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx